# How to remove decimal and number after decimal in r

Tags: r, file, csv

My file is like this`(1822306 long file)`-

```
colIDs  rowIDs
1   NBAS    NBAS
2   DNAH9   DNAH9
3   NRAS    NRAS
4   NRAS.1  NRAS
5   TP53    TP53
6   TP53.1  TP53
7   SCYL2   TP53
8   RNF19A  SCYL2
```

I want to `remove after decimal value including decimal(.)` from this file

Comment: You can also do `df1 %>% mutate(colIDs = str_remove("colIDs, "\\.\\d+$"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
Data$colIDs = sub("\\..*", "", Data$colIDs)
```

`\\.` selects the (first) period and `.*` includes everything afterwards. These are replaced with the empty string.